# How to connect a code to animate a photo on LaunchScreen.storyborad?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically I try this code in ViewController first to show animation in LaunchScreen page but its not work and animation showed up in first view controller not in LaunchScreen , so what's your idea?

here is the code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
private let imageView : UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0 , width: 150, height : 150 ))

}()
    
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * .pi) / 180.0)
     })
}

   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "animationLogo", in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)
}
```

Comment: `UIView.animate` doesn't work in `viewDidLoad`. Put it in `viewDidAppear` instead.

Comment: @aheze but it is working on viewController.swift and just I want to show it on lunchScreen

Comment: What do you mean by "to show animation in LaunchScreen page"?

Comment: @ElTomato I mean I have a png photo in my launchScreen.storyBoard that I want to show this photo with animation before start my viewcontrollers.

Comment: You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run any kind of animations in launch screen , you need to create an initial view controller and set the animations needed inside it , then navigate to your home screen

Comment: thank you for your guid , how can I  navigate initial view controller from lunchScreen into homeScreen(view controller)?

Comment: you need to make initial vc the entry point in IB then after animation finishes navigate with present/push/segue

Comment: you need to make initial vcc the entry point in IB then after animation finishes navigate with present/push/segue

Comment: initial vc must be create in main.storyBoard or lunchScreen? and what is IB?

Comment: in main , IB is interface builder which is the storyboard

Comment: oh thanks , and do I need to remove entry point of lunch screen?